# If we have a set of n linearly independent vectors in $R^n$, does that mean they span $R^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I know that they will form a basis, but will they span the entire $R^n$?

Comment: Yes. A basis spans the space and is linearly independent.

Comment: @copper.hat Ok good, just want to make sure that my intuition is correct